# How do I add a required field to a model that I didn't write?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I'm using Django 3, Python 3.7, and the django-address module -- https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address .  I would like to indicate that the State field of the Locality model is required.  Since I didn't write the model myself, I'm not quite sure how to do that.  I created the below serializer ...

```
class AddressTypeField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    queryset = Address.objects

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            locality = data['locality']
            state = None if not re.match(r"[0-9]+", str(locality['state'])) else State.objects.get(pk=locality['state']) 
            locality['state'] = state
            locality, created = Locality.objects.get_or_create(**locality)
            data['locality'] = locality
            address = Address.objects.create(**data)
            # Replace the dict with the ID of the newly obtained object
            data = address.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
...

class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True, allow_empty=False)
    addresses = AddressTypeField(many=True)
    phone = ContactMethodPhoneSerializer()
    email = ContactMethodEmailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['types'] = CoopTypeSerializer(instance.types.all(), many=True).data
        rep['addresses'] = AddressSerializer(instance.addresses.all(), many=True).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """

        coop_types = validated_data.pop('types', {})
        phone = validated_data.pop('phone', {})
        email = validated_data.pop('email', {})
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for item in coop_types:
            coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(name=item['name']) 
            instance.types.add(coop_type)
        instance.phone = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.PHONE, **phone)
        instance.email = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.EMAIL, **email)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Coop` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        try:
            coop_types = validated_data['types']
            instance.types.clear()  # Disassociates all  CoopTypes from instance.
            for item in coop_types:
                coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**item)
                instance.types.add(coop_type)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        instance.addresses = validated_data.get('addresses', instance.addresses)
        instance.enabled = validated_data.get('enabled', instance.enabled)
        phone = validated_data.pop('phone', {})
        email = validated_data.pop('email', {})
        instance.phone = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.PHONE, **phone)
        instance.email = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.EMAIL, **email)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

but when I run a test through my serializer (below),

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create_with_no_state(self):
    """ Test coop serizlizer model """
    name = "Test 8899"
    coop_type_name = "Library"
    street = "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212"
    city = "Chicago"
    postal_code = "60654"
    enabled = True
    postal_code = "60654"
    email = "test@example.com"
    phone = "7739441422"
    web_site = "http://www.1871.com"
    serializer_data = {
        "name": name,
        "types": [
            {"name": coop_type_name}
        ],
        "addresses": [{
            "formatted": street,
            "locality": {
                "name": city,
                "postal_code": postal_code,
                "state": ''
            }
        }],
        "enabled": enabled,
        "phone": {
          "phone": phone
        },
        "email": {
          "email": email
        },
        "web_site": web_site
    }

    serializer = CoopSerializer(data=serializer_data)
    assert not serializer.is_valid()
    assert len(serializer.errors.keys()) == 1
    assert serializer.errors['phone']['phone'][0].code == "invalid_phone_number"
```

it results in the error, instead of creating a validation error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_serializers.py", line 142, in test_coop_create_with_no_state
    assert not serializer.is_valid()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 234, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 433, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 490, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 565, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 519, in to_internal_value
    return [
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 520, in <listcomp>
    self.child_relation.to_internal_value(item)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/directory/serializers.py", line 33, in to_internal_value
    locality, created = Locality.objects.get_or_create(**locality)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 562, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(kwargs, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 604, in _create_object_from_params
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 596, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1377, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'state_id' cannot be null")
```

How can I add a required field to my model given that I'm not in control of the model code?

Comment: `I would like to indicate that the State field of the Locality model is required` and error `Column 'state_id' cannot be null`; by default it is mandatory and in `serializer_data`, data inside `state` is missing that's why it is giving `IntegrityError`. By any chance you want to make it optional?

Comment: If State field is required, shouldn't validation return an error instead of attempting to save the entity to the database?

Comment: Yup it should, changing `assert not serializer.is_valid()` to `assert serializer.is_valid()` will give `AssertionError`. Right now it is letting it execute next line; `assert not False` gives `assert True`. And if you are adamant on using `assert` fit it inside `try` and `except AssertionError`, it will be easier and more readable that way.

Comment: For some reason the validation seems to be calling the AddressTypeField's to_internal_value method, which is ultimately generating the error.  I "think" I need to keep that method as it is so that creating a Coop with the serializer can succeed, but it seems to be interfering with the validation.

Comment: You should be saving stuff in save() not in to_internal_value(). If a later field denies validation, than what is the ghost Locality doing in the database? Look at [writeable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) on how to do this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the **`state`** emptynes in **`AddressTypeField`** field as,

```
class AddressTypeField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    queryset = Address.objects

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            locality = data['locality']
            state = None if not re.match(r"[0-9]+", str(locality['state'])) else State.objects.get(pk=locality['state'])

            if not state:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'state': 'This field is required.'})

            locality['state'] = state
            locality, created = Locality.objects.get_or_create(**locality)
            data['locality'] = locality
            address = Address.objects.create(**data)
            # Replace the dict with the ID of the newly obtained object
            data = address.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a more out-of-the-box solution I can take advantage of?  It seems like I should be able just to specify a "blank=False" or "empty=false" somewhere or something like that.

Comment: It would've been possible if you were not overridden the `to_internal_value(...)` method. If we look at your code-base, the `state` is determined by *some magical logic* and I don't think there will be a better way to *replace* the logic (as I didn't understand the logic :P )

Answer (score 0):

by default django comes with up with a user field with email not required and if you want to make that required or you want to change the model you didn't write you can do something like this

Place this in any of your models.py.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
Then run makemigrations. Then run migrate.
```

Done!